# How do I let CPython 2.7 use the __pycache__ directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpython, pyc

CPython 3.x and PyPy follow [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) and store pyc-files in  `__pycache__` directories with a Python version suffix attached to them. **How can I force CPython 2.7 to store its pyc-files in `__pycache__` directories** as well (opposed to its default behavior of storing pyc-files without suffix right next to the corresponding py-files in the same directory)?

I realize that I should probably not do this system-wide because a lot of other software expects CPython 2.x's default behavior. So what I am looking for is a way to do this per project or per virtual environment or, if there is no other solution, per custom compiled and custom installed (e.g. in `~/bin`) CPython interpreter.

---

Some research: [Relevant discussion](https://lists.debian.org/debian-python/2010/04/msg00046.html) on Debian mailing list; [code review](https://codereview.appspot.com/842043/#ps13001) for PEP 3147 implementation in CPython 3.2.

Comment: I found another archived discussion that shed's light on why this wasn't back-ported, take a look at it if you'd like.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Thanks, I just looked at it. It is somewhat strange that this was not back-ported as an optional feature though as the PEP suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the [backports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#backports) section of PEP 3147 alludes to the possibility of it being back ported:

> For versions of Python earlier than 3.2 (and *possibly* 2.7), it is possible to backport this PEP. However, in Python 3.2 (and *possibly* 2.7), this behavior will be turned on by default, and in fact, it will replace the old behavior.

This was not done as far as I know. The discussion [here](https://lists.gt.net/python/dev/815877?do=post_vew_threaded) indicates why:

> I would prefer that this not be in 2.7. The patch may be simple to 
>   port, but it represents quite a change in an eons old Python behvior.

That's the reply from the release manager for Python 2.7, he (correctly imho) didn't want this feature back ported.

In the end, your only option is implementing it yourself (which is a non-trivial task).